# uploadify email notification

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Is it possible for "Uploadify" to send out e-mail confirmation after the upload?

Uploadify is a jQuery plugin that allows the easy integration of a multiple (or single) file uploads on your website.  It requires Flash and any backend development language.  An array of options allow for full customization for advanced users, but basic implementation is so easy that even coding novices can do it.

here is the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#uploadify").uploadify({
        'uploader'       : 'scripts/uploadify.swf',
        'script'         : 'scripts/uploadify.php',
        'cancelImg'      : 'cancel.png',
        'folder'         : 'uploads',
        'auto'           : true,
        'multi'          : true,
        'onComplete'   : function(event, queueID, fileObj, response, data) {
                         $('#message').html( 'files were successfully uploaded');
                         $('#message').show().animate({'display':'block'},3000).hide(500);
                       }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: You might want to explain what "uploadify" is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to add the email sending functionality to your scripts/uploadify.php file.

Comment: ok thanks. Do I doa  php include in index.php to call the uploadify.php or is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

Create a PHP script that sends the mail.

Use Uploadify's onAllComplete handler to make a final XmlHttpRequest (AJAX) call to your shiny new email-sending script.

Lots of details to fill in, but this is probably the best direction to take.

Comment: is it also possible to print out the link of the file that was just uploaded.. With the e-mail notification